# Python DB connection closing, using try catch inside a finally clause

Tags: python-3.x

So i wanna know what is more efficient closing connection in Finally clause or having an explicit **try catch** statement inside a finally is a better approach.

```
    try: #some try logic
    except:
        print("something")
    finally:
        try:
            my_db_session.close()
        except:
            pass
```

or this 1

```
    try: #some try logic
    except:
        print(traceback.print_exc())
    finally:
        my_db_session.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this depends on whether you care about the exception raised by `my_db_session.close()` or not. `try: except: pass` ignores that exception, but it could be better to let the caller handle it.

As for efficiency, by which you probably mean speed, I'd say there's absolutely no speed penalty for one more `try/except` statement.

If by efficiency you mean "making sure that the connection is definitely closed", this depends on what `my_db_session.close()` does in case of an exception. The `finally` clause is *always* executed, so `my_db_session.close()` will definitely be called.